# Read uncommited data in smple connect

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, commit

Is it possible (in SQL SERVER 2012) to read data before update in one transaction.
Example:
I have one table, name: tab with two columns col1 and col2. I have one record: col1 = 1 and col2 = 'a'

```
begin transaction
update tab set col2 = 'A' where col1 = 1
-- here i want to read data before update (in this example 'a')
-- here i want to read data after update (in this example 'A')
Committ transaction
```

Before committ transaction when using select always i get data after update (in this example 'A'). I try to do

```
select * from tab with(nolock)
```

but it doesn't work.
Question: In section: after update and before committ - can i read data which was before update ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Locking hints determine how nicely you read data that is being updated by *another* transaction. But code that runs in a transaction always sees changes made earlier in the same  transaction.

If you need the old state, why not store the old version in a variable?  Like:

```
begin transaction
declare @old_col2 int
select @old_col2 = col2 from tab where id = 1
update tab set col2 = 'A' where id = 1
... now you can access both the old and the new data ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know i can store old data, but i don't want to do this. So in your opinion it is impossible ?

Comment: If you're feeling hackish, you could try querying from a linked server (you can link a server to itself.)  That basically puts you outside your transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can achieve the same using below sample :

USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
    EmpID int NOT NULL,
    OldVacationHours int,
    NewVacationHours int,
    ModifiedDate datetime);

UPDATE TOP (10) HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = VacationHours * 1.25,
    ModifiedDate = GETDATE() 
OUTPUT inserted.BusinessEntityID,
       deleted.VacationHours,
       inserted.VacationHours,
       inserted.ModifiedDate
INTO @MyTableVar;

--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT EmpID, OldVacationHours, NewVacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM @MyTableVar;
GO
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT TOP (10) BusinessEntityID, VacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```

This is elegant solution instead of writing seperate SELECTs in the code.
Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177564.aspx